# Как вызвать функцию, находящуюся в другой функции?

Tags: python

Какое то время, у меня была проблема, YouTube Guides оп питону не помогали. Суть вопроса:

Как вызвать функцию, находящуюся в другой функции?

Добавлю код для более простого понимания:

```
def function1(): #Первая функция
   print("Hello World!")
   def function2(): #Функция которую нужно вызвать из первой функции.
      print("World is answer: Hello!")
```

Я задал этот вопрос, не просто так. Я заметил, что ни на форумах, не на GitHab-е, даже здесь, на ruSO, нету ясного, и понятного ответа, как так сделать.

Я много чего пробовал, пытаясь даже костылями вызвать(Код кривой, в силу что был написан очень давно, когда только познал базовые знания питона):

```
def func1():
   prit("Hello world!")
   def func2():
      print("Call func from funck is successfully!")

func(fucn2())
```

Вот неясно, как и что, ведь выдаёт ошибку:

```
D:\Terminalius\TermNet\$cash>func2.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Terminalius\TermNet\$cash\func2.py", line 6, in <module>
    func(fucn2())
NameError: name 'func' is not defined
```

Что бы вы не подумали что код неправильный, вот скриншот из редактора:
[image: Скриншот из редактора кода.]

Comment: Правило видимости имен запрещает это делать. Возможно как-то через рефлексию это можно сделать, если такая есть в питоне и доступ к "деткам" ф-ции там реализован.

Comment: @nick_n_a, Как я уже уточнил в вопросе, Интернет и YouTube информацию даже о том что ты написал не даёт, а мой Английский не позволяет прочитать полную документацию о питоне на Официальной странице питона, переводчик переводит не точно, и не верно в некоторых местах, т.к машинный перевод, что кстати не удивляет. Кстати, костыли для обхода этого правила принимаются. =)

Comment: А зачем? Обычно такие вещи принято реализовывать с помощью ООП, т.е. создаёте класс, и наполняете класс нужными методами.

Comment: никак, такие функции можно вызвать только внутри головной функции и нигде за ее пределами.

Comment: @nick_n_a, Ну да, конечно это всё верно, видел ответы на подобии: "Есть ООП и Классы в питоне", но проблема в том, что в одном из своих ранее вопросов, я более подробно объяснил, что Классы пока-что не моё, в силу возраста и прочих факторов. Просто в другом проекте, требовалось именно такое решение.

Comment: @Argo7, Вообще? Даже через костыли?

Comment: @TerminaliusDeveloper а дайте реальный пример? Если вы в такой ситуации, то видимо это проблемы организации кода, если эта функция пригодилась за пределами головной функции. Обычно так делают, если в рамках одной функции часто переиспользуется код или не хочется хранить состояние

Comment: Эмм... Как бы правильно сформулировать. Был проект QSS(Qui Sub System), и когда начинал его создавать, подразумевалось использование 2 функций друг в друге, но вызов их был в отдельной третьей функции. Были две основные функции: `files`, `commands`. И была третья функция: `system`. Первые две, отвечали за открытие файлов в системе, и за команды, которые вводит пользователь в систему, для манипуляции. и как бы первые две, находились в третьей, но при это, последняя(третья функция) вызывалось отдельно, и требовалось что бы из последней, при необходимости можно было вызвать одну из двух функций

Comment: Но я также упёрся в проблему описанную в моём вопросе, функции не были видны. В итоге проект закрыл, но вопрос остался. Исходный код проекта, переделал, и эта необходимость, точнее задумка отпала сама собой.

Comment: Можно было-бы, скинул бы его сюда, но из-за ограничений ruSO по символам в 30к в вопросе, не могу, а код по символам более 30к.

Comment: "проблема в том, что в одном из своих ранее вопросов, я более подробно объяснил, что Классы пока-что не моё, в силу возраста и прочих факторов." - это отмазка, не более. Никогда не рано начинать изучать ООП.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам срочно надо освоить **`ООП`**. Ну, а попробовать можно так:

```
def func1(flag=0):
    def func2():
        print("Call func from funck is successfully!")
   
    if flag:
        print("Hello world!")
    else:
        func2()

func1()
func1(1)
```

Comment: Ну я приму, но он выводит сразу. В проекте который закрыл ещё с Апреля этого года, необходимость была в том, что бы вызывать по отдельности. Ну ладно, оно работает, спасибо!

Comment: @TerminaliusDeveloper уточните, пожалуйста, что значит по отдельности и я поправлю пример как вам надо.

Comment: Извиняюсь за долгое отсутствие, по отдельности имелось ввиду, что нужен был массив этих самовызывающихся функций, и вся суть была в том, что вводом команды в псевдо "консоль" я мог вызвать любую функцию какую мне нужно было из этого массива.

Answer (score 1):

Это возможно только если в явном виде вернуть указатель на внутреннюю функцию из внешней функции. На подобном принципе, кстати, работают декораторы:

```
def function1(): #Первая функция
   print("Hello World!")
   def function2(): #Функция которую нужно вызвать из первой функции.
      print("World is answer: Hello!")
   return function2

function1()   # вызываем внешнюю функцию, возврат игнорируем
function1()() # вызываем внешнюю функцию, возврат вызываем как функцию
```

Вывод:

```
Hello World!
Hello World!
World is answer: Hello!
```

Answer (score 0):

Функцию в функции тоже нужно вызвать.

```
def function1(): #Первая функция
    print("Hello World!")
    def function2(): #Функция которую нужно вызвать из первой функции.
        print("World is answer: Hello!")
    function2()

function1()
```

Вывод:

```
Hello World!
World is answer: Hello!
```